# ENSwiftSideMenu shadow in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the [ENSwiftSideMenu](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu)-library as a sidemenu in my application. I want to give the whole menu a little shadow on the right, but only when it is open. The menu itself is a UITableView.

I am wondering how I should approach this. I now gave the UITableView a shadow, but I guess that it is not appearing because it would be outside of the superview the menu is in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. In the ENSideMenu.swift file I added this to `setupMenuView()`: (it was already there but I removed it sometime ago)

```
sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5.0, 5.0)
sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
sideMenuContainerView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: sideMenuContainerView.bounds).CGPath
```